# What is the radius of a planet, given some basic information?

Tags: trigonometry

Suppose you are travelling through a planetary system.  From your space ship you view planet X.  The planet is known to be spherical.  As you view planet X, the angle from the centre of the planet to the outer edge of the planet is 3 degrees.  The distance from your space ship to the nearest surface of the planet is 100,000 miles.  What is the exact radius of the planet to the nearest tenth of a mile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the right triangle made of the observer, the planet center and the "horizon" on the surfac (where the right angle is), we find
$$ \sin \alpha = \frac r{r+d}$$
where $\alpha=3^\circ$ is the observed angle, $d=100{,}000\,\text{mi}$ (or nm?) is the observed distance. 
Solving for $r$, we find 
$$ r = \frac{d\sin\alpha}{1-\sin\alpha}$$
Your pocket calculator should be able to evaluate this (to check your computation: the result looks like $x{,}xxx.x276\ldots\,\text{mi}$)

Comment: I fully concur.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we are allowed to use trigonometric tables,

Draw a diagram. Let $A$ be your position. Let $B$ be the nearest point on the surface of the planet. Let $C $be its centre. And let $D$ be the outer edge of it visible to you.

We can assume that the two lines $AD$ and $AC$ create a $3^{\circ}$ angle between them. Now the data given says $AB = 100,000$ miles. And we can assume the points,  $A, B$ and $C$ lie on the same line. So,

$$\cos 3^{\circ} = \dfrac{ 100,000 + BC}{CD } \;\; BC = CD = r$$

where $r$ is the radius of the planet.